# Class reference another two classes

Tags: c++

I have two classes with some methods with same name.
Can I create third class that accept reference from ony of the other two and in the constructor to set obj variable to A or B type?

```
class A
{
    public:
        A();        
        void f();
};

class B
{
    public:
        B();        
        void f();
};

class C
{
    public:
        C(B&);
        C(A&);

    ??? obj;
};
```

Comment: Yes, but how you do it depends on what those classes represent and how you use them. Should `C` have an `A` or `B` member which is decided at compile time? In that case use templates. Do `A` and `B` represent specialized implementations of common behaviour? Then make a base class and use inheritance and virtual functions.

Comment: If both `A` and `B` where sub classes of `X` then you could declare `obj` as `X`

Comment: How about [Boost variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you want a template class:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
    T& obj;
    public:
        explicit C(T& t) : obj(t) {}
        void f() { obj.f(); }
};
```

And then:

```
A a;
B b;
C<A> c1(a);
C<B> c2(b);
c1.f();
c2.f();
```

Comment: @selfbg This is what C++ templates work for. C++ templates provide compile-time polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is a very flexible language and as such provides multiple options for what you are asking for. Each with their own pros and cons.

The first route that comes to mind is to use polymorphism.
You have two routes to choose from: static or dynamic polymorphism.

**The Static Polymorphic Route**

To use static polymorphism (also known as compile-time polymorphism) you should make `C` a template class:

```
template <typename T> class C
{
    public:
        C(T&);

        T& obj;
}
```

**The Dynamic Polymorphic Route**

To use dynamic (also known as run-time polymorphism) you should provide an interface:

```
class Fer
{
    public:
        virtual ~Fer() {}

        virtual void f() = 0;
}
```

Which `A` and `B` would implement:

```
class A : public Fer
{
    public:
        A();        
        void f() overide;
};

class B : public Fer
{
    public:
        B();        
        void f() overide;
};
```

`C` would then be like this:

```
class C
{
    public:
        C(Fer&);

        Fer& obj;
}
```

**The Variant Route**

There are various libraries that provide classes that can safely hold arbitrary types.

Some examples of these are:

- [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html)
- [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html)
- [QVariant from Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html)

When using such classes you generally need some means of converting back to the actual type before operating on it.

Comment: There's also the `boost::variant` route which is often better than intrusive interface inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a base class that defines the required interface.

```
class Base
{
    public:
        Base();
        virtual void f();
};
```

And you can have derived classes that implement the interface.

```
class A : public Base
{
    public:
        A();
        virtual void f();
};

class B : public Base
{
    public:
        B();
        virtual void f();
};
```

The class `C` then refers to the `Base` class and can actually accept objects of `A` or `B` type.

```
class C
{
    private:
        Base& base;

    public:
        C(Base& b) : base(b) {}
};
```

It can be easily used then.

```
int main()
{
    B b;
    C c(b);
    return 0;
}
```